# How to get to know when remote host is down in SSH?

Tags: python, ssh, libssh2, libssh, parallel-ssh

When using `OpenSSH` from command line, we can use `-o ServerAliveInterval=30 -o ServerAliveCountMax=2` to timeout the command if server do not respond to keepalive packets.

Similary, when using `ssh2-python` in blocking mode, which is based on `libssh2`, it is sufficient to set `session.keepalive_config(_, 60)` for similar behaviour.

But when using the same library in non-blocking mode, this won't work. All of the channel functions, including `wait_eof`, return `LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN`. So, if connection is lost in between, these functions will wait forever and never exit. How to avoid this?

Comment: Is there a way to `keepalive_recv` similar to `keepalive_send`?